# 3rd Button on UI Seems to not Register the onClick.AddListener()

Tags: unity, c#, events, unity-ui

I have a `UIManager` meant to control the UI. The UI manager is attached to an empty game object.

The `Canvas` has three panels, each with a button. All the panels are initially set to inactive in the inspector.

When I run the program, the `WelcomePanel` displays. When I click the button on `WelcomePanel`, it closes the panel and sets the `GenerateTerrainPanel` to active *as intended*.

When I click the button on the `GenerateTerrainPane`l, it generates the terrain - so I know the call to the other class is working (*this method takes 4-5 minutes to execute*), and it closes the panel and then sets the `BuildTownCenterPanel` to active *as intended*.

But the button on that panel (`BuildTownCenterPanel`) will not execute the code attached to it.

I'm a noob, and way out of my league and trying to learn as I build my project. I thought I was understanding delegates/actions, and I do understand them enough to make the call across classes happen, but I cannot figure why this button doesn't seem to register the method passed in the `onClick.AddListener()` for the life of me. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Yes - `buildTownCenterBtn` is set to Interactable in the Inspector.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class UIManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    // KEEP YOUR METHODS SIMPLE!

    // Create Actions
    Action onGenerateTerrain;
    

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject generateTerrainPanel, welcomePanel, buildTownCenterPanel;
    [SerializeField]
    private Button welcomeGetStartedBtn, buildTownCenterBtn, generateTerrainBtn;

   
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        // Add all our button listeners.
        welcomeGetStartedBtn.onClick.AddListener(onWelcomeGetStartedCallBack);
        generateTerrainBtn.onClick.AddListener(onGenerateTerrainCallBack);
        buildTownCenterBtn.onClick.AddListener(onBuildTownCenterCallBack);
                
        ShowWelcomePanel();
                        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
        
    }

    // Define button callbacks.
    private void onWelcomeGetStartedCallBack()
    {
        HideWelcomePanel();
        ShowTerrainGeneratorPanel();
    }
    private void onGenerateTerrainCallBack()
    {
        // Call the GenerateNewTerrain() in TerrainGenerator.cs.
        onGenerateTerrain?.Invoke();
        // Call the method to show the next panel.        
        ShowBuildTownCenterPanel();
                
    }

    private void onBuildTownCenterCallBack()
    {
        Debug.Log("This button works! You made it to onBuildTownCenterCallBack()!");
    }

    
    // This method allows GameManager.cs to assign the GenerateNewTerrain() in TerrainGenerator.cs to the onGenerateTerrain action.
    public void AddListenerOnGenerateTerrain(Action listener)
    {
        onGenerateTerrain += listener;
    }

    
    // Handle panels.
    private void ShowTerrainGeneratorPanel()
    {
        generateTerrainPanel.SetActive(true);
                        
    }

    private void HideTerrainGeneratorPanel()
    {
        // I think the ? either ensures it's not null, or checks to see if it's active.
        generateTerrainPanel?.SetActive(false);
    }

    private void ShowWelcomePanel()
    {
        welcomePanel.SetActive(true);
        
    }

    private void HideWelcomePanel()
    {
        welcomePanel.SetActive(false);
    }

    private void ShowBuildTownCenterPanel()
    {
        generateTerrainPanel?.SetActive(false);
        buildTownCenterPanel.SetActive(true);
                
    }

    

}
```

Comment: Where is `buildTownCenterBtn` assigned? Do you see any output including warnings or errors in your debug console when compiling and running this script?

Comment: @DMGregory buildTownCenterBtn is assigned in the inspector. That's why I used [SerializedField] in my declaration. There is no warnings or errors in Visual Studio or in the Inspector. I'll try to get a video up on my channel and link to it so you can see the what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

I found it. When I call the method GenerateNewTerrain(), is start by destroying all the game objects in the world unless they have a certain tag.

```
public void DestroyAllGameObjects()
    {
        GameObject[] GameObjects = (FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>() as GameObject[]);

        for (int i = 0; i < GameObjects.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!GameObjects[i].CompareTag("MainCamera") && !GameObjects[i].CompareTag("Light") && !GameObjects[i].CompareTag("EmptyObject") && !GameObjects[i].CompareTag("Terrain") && !GameObjects[i].CompareTag("UI"))
            {
                //Debug.Log("This ain't the camera.");
                Destroy(GameObjects[i]);
            }
            
        }
    }
```

When I had created my UIController as an empty game object, I never gave it a tag. Therefore, my GenerateNewTerrain() method was destroying the game object and the UIManager.cs that was attached to it, so the button had no script to control its behavior.

[image]

I discovered it this morning as I sat down to make a video to help you all understand.

This simple mistake has driven me mad for 3 or 4 days.

Thanks for taking a look, and for your willingness to help. Crisis averted for now.

Respectfully,
Tim